# Input field with buttons or spans inside

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a feature in mind for an interface I'm developing but I'm not entirely sure of how to bring it to fruition. I'm basically after an input field with a set of buttons to the side which insert a span/button inside the input to represent the button clicked.

So in a simplified version of my imagined interface, I can type into the field as normal but when I press one of the buttons to the side, they also insert text into the field. Let's say if I press button 1 it inserts the text "Hello" and button 2 inserts the text "Emma". Fairly easy.

The more complex version which I want to create works similarly, but when I click button 1 it inserts a bubble inside the text field. The bubble has its own background colour, contains the word "Hello" and has a small x in the top right to dismiss it. When the bubble is inserted it moves the carat on past the inserted bubble and I can continue to type as normal. If I hit backspace when the carat is to the right of the bubble, it deletes the entire bubble at once. Here's a simple example image:

[image: example image]

I feel like I've seen this kind of thing on the internet a lot but I can't work out how it's done. Is there a way to pull this off with an input field? If it's not possible which alternatives should I be looking into?

Comment: *"I feel like I've seen this kind of thing on the internet a lot..."* Including here on SO, in the tags field. :-)

Comment: Haha I didn't notice that but yes that's almost exactly what I'm after! I can see how the SO implementation works now that I look at the source (It seems to just shrink the input box and put it to the right of the tags) but unfortunately it turns everything into a tag which wouldn't work for me - I need to be able to put typed text in between the bubbles.

Comment: It's the same concept as putting bubbles there, just different styling. :-)

Comment: I don't think you can do this with an input, unless you do some really have changes to the standard behaviour of an input. Your best best would be to have another element contain a set of elements (also including an input, of course) and then handle their behaviour programmatically... I'll try to explain better in an answer

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this with just an `input` unless you go change the standard implementation of input for your page :)

I think your best bet would be to have a structure like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="shownContent">Is that <div class="tag">Emma</div></div>
  <input class="underlyingInput"/>
  <div class="tagsButtons" />
</div>
```

- `undelyingInput` is hidden - available but hidden.
- Style `shownContent` to look like an input.
- You then handle clicks on `shownContent`: if they click shown content, focus the hidden underlying input, BUT show `shownContent` as focused.
- Now if the users start to write after they clicked on `shownContent`, that text is actually going into the input!
- When value changes in the input, use the new value to parse it into text and tags, and set the html content of `shownContent`

Once you got this, removing tags from clicks on the left and adding them from clicks on the right should be straightforward.

Comment: So one issue with this is the caret. I can get it to select the hidden input form okay, but the caret is obviously not visible on screen. I also can't think of any way to get the caret to move to the correct location in the hidden input form. For example if I click to place my caret between the first and second characters on the visible div this doesn't put the carat into the correct place on the hidden input form.

Comment: Yes the caret is problematic... There is a function to manually set the selection range https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange with which you can force all the text to be selected, or force the caret to be in a specific position in the underlying input. From there you could track all changes to the caret position with an event listener, or by tracking the value in the input, and use this to display a fake caret. The more limitations you add, the easier it gets to implement

Comment: If you say *new text will always go at the end* and *backspace always deletes everything* it becomes really easy to handle. If you want it to be as free as possible, it gets complicated

Comment: If you used a fixed-width font and made sure that your tags were also of a fixed width, you could calculate the caret position based on the click location.

Or if you're married to the idea of having a non-fixed-width font, you could even have each character occupy its own `<span>`, and then check which one was clicked (and calculate whether its left or right half was clicked).

Comment: @JosephO'Donnell Now that you made me think about it, you can also compute it with dynamic font-style and width! It just gets harder because you need informations about the font in use... Ex: https://github.com/adambisek/string-pixel-width

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a series of inputs, instead of just one:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input /> <!-- "Is that " -->
  <button>Emma</button>
  <input /> <!-- "? " -->
  <button>Hello</button>
  <input /> <!-- ", " -->
  <button>Emma</button>
  <input /> <!-- "!" -->
</div>
```

The wrapper is just for styling purposes: you'd give it a border and make the `input` elements borderless.

You'd need to override a lot of keyboard commands on the `input` elements. For example, backspacing at the beginning of that last `input` would cause the preceding button to be deleted, and merge the contents of the two adjacent `input` elements.

You'd also need to consider the effect of hitting the Home and End keys (and equivalents in other OSes).

Moreover, you'd wanna make sure the `input` elements will resize as their contents change. It's a little tricky, but doable!

Here's a jumping off point: https://codepen.io/exonj/pen/jxQxGV

Answer (score -1):

This is a tagsinput. Checkout this
[Bootstrap TagsInput](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/). It has the same functionality as you wanted.